# What exactly is the "Allow Non-modular includes in Framework Modules" setting?

Tags: ios, xcode, static-libraries, cocoa-touch

I see a lot of threads online suggesting to change the **"Allow Non-modular includes in Framework Modules"** Build Setting to **"Yes"** but nowhere can I find an explanation of what exactly this Build Setting does! Is anyone able to explain what it is or does or point me to some links where this is explained?

A bit of context about my problem: I am developing a Cocoa Touch Framework which has a dependency on a `.a` library. I am unable to use any of the headers of the `.a` library in the public headers of my Framework. Well, I can and my Framework builds but when I add it to my application then those headers can't be found. (Changing the **"Allow Non-modular includes in Framework Modules"** setting to **"Yes"** allows my Framework to build but does not solve the subsequent problem of it being usable in my application.)

Answer (score 0):

I've found [this GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/NSExceptional/2cd98300f7297b75d7b2d929effa2f15) to be a good searchable reference for Xcode Build Settings.

According to that Gist (see [here](https://gist.github.com/NSExceptional/2cd98300f7297b75d7b2d929effa2f15#allow-non-modular-includes-in-framework-modules-clang_allow_non_modular_includes_in_framework_modules)) the "Allow Non-modular Includes In Framework Modules" Build Setting's purpose is as follows:

> Enabling this setting allows non-modular includes to be used from
>   within framework modules. This is inherently unsafe, as such headers
>   might cause duplicate definitions when used by any client that imports
>   both the framework and the non-modular includes.